# Function sometimes randomly calling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i am making a board/card game Carcassonne. I have prefab cards and every card has four variables s, v, j, z (world compass in my language). I have a function that finds a side with a value "R" (stands for road) and finds card that is next to it (thanks to the location of cards). For example if s == "R" it calls the second function, that finds the tile on top of the card and sets variable lastSide to "j" so that when the first function is called again it doesnt go back. Road is always only on two side so thats why there is "nicovani". I hope this is not hard to understand, the problem is sometimes when i lay a card the function is called once from the card layed and once from the card layed before, then once again from the card just layed. I have no idea why, but its the last thing i need to solve to complete this. If've read this far i am already thankful. Here's the important code:

```
    public string s;
    public string v;
    public string j;
    public string z;
    private int cross = 0;
    public bool Layed;
    public bool IsRoadEnding;
    private string lastSide;
    private int nicovani = 0;
    private bool isScored = false;


    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(Layed == false)
        {
            if(r == 1)
            {
                r = 2;
                IsHere = false;
                StartCoroutine(Follow());
            }
            else 
            {
                if(IsHere == true)
                {
                    TheWholeThing();
                }
                
                else
                {
                    r = 1;
                    transform.position = spawner.transform.position;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void TheWholeThing()
    {
        setPos = new Vector2 (Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.y));
        r = 1;
        transform.position = setPos;
        FindTile();
        CheckTile(asociatedTile);

        if(r == 1)
        {
            drawer.SpawnCard();

            SetTile(asociatedTile);
            
            gmg.GenerateGrid(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+1, "j" , s);
            gmg.GenerateGrid(transform.position.x, transform.position.y-1, "s", j);
            gmg.GenerateGrid(transform.position.x +1, transform.position.y, "z", v);
            gmg.GenerateGrid(transform.position.x -1, transform.position.y, "v", z);
        
            Layed = true;

            startingTile = gameObject.transform;
            if(nicovani < 2)
            {
                FindScoringRoad(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, "", s, v, j, z);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        IsHere = false;
    }


    void FindScoringRoad(float x, float y, string side, string s, string v, string j, string z)
    {
        if(isScored == false)
        {
            lastSide = side;

            if(lastSide != "s")
            {
                if(s == "R")
                {
                    cross = 0;
                    Debug.Log("s");
                    FindNextCard("j", x, y + 1);
                }
            }

            if(lastSide != "v")
            {
                if(v == "R")
                {
                    cross = 0;
                    Debug.Log("v");
                    FindNextCard("z", x + 1, y);
                }
            }

            if(lastSide != "j")
            {
                if(j == "R")
                {
                    if(nicovani == 2)
                    {
                        nicovani = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cross = 0;
                        Debug.Log("j");
                        FindNextCard("s", x , y - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
          
            if(lastSide != "z")
            {
                if(z == "R")
                {
                    if(nicovani == 2)
                    {
                        nicovani = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cross = 0;
                        Debug.Log("z");
                        Debug.Log(x + " " + y);
                        FindNextCard("v", x - 1, y);
                    }
                }
            }
            cross = 0;
            return;
        }
    }

    void FindNextCard(string side, float x, float y)
    {
        if(x == startingTile.position.x & y == startingTile.position.y)
        {
            Debug.Log("Road Closed");
            isScored = true;
            return;
        }

        foreach(GameObject card in drawer.spawnedCards)
        {
            if(card.transform.position.x == x & card.transform.position.y == y)
            {
                var cardS = card.GetComponent<Card>();
                if(cross < 1)
                {
                    FindScoringRoad(card.transform.position.x, card.transform.position.y, side, cardS.s, cardS.v, cardS.j, cardS.z);
                    cross++;
                }          
                return;
            }         
        }

        Debug.Log("Ends here");
        cross = 0;
        nicovani++;
        return;
    }
```

The code describes what i tried so far. Thanks for any help, it means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the problem is sometimes when i lay a card the function is called once
> from the card layed and once from the card layed before, then once
> again from the card just layed.

So the problem is `FindScordingRoad` is called three times and you only expect twice? I think this is your problem.

```
void FindScoringRoad(float x, float y, string side, string s, string v, string j, string z)
{
    // we enter this function so this method has been called once
    // assuming s and v equals "R" but not j and z
    if (isScored == false)
    {
        lastSide = side;
        // lastSide == "" so we enter if below.
        if (lastSide != "s")
        {
            // as per assumption this is true and we enter if
            if (s == "R")
            {
                ...
                // This will call FindScoringRoad a second time
                FindNextCard("j", x, y + 1);
            }
        }

        // lastSide == "" still so we enter if below.
        if (lastSide != "v")
        {
            // as per assumption this is true and we enter if
            if (v == "R")
            {
                ...
                // This will call FindScoringRoad a third time
                FindNextCard("z", x + 1, y);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You can fix this by setting cross=0 and returning right after `FindNextCard`

```
if (lastSide != "s")
{
    if (s == "R")
    {
        cross = 0;
        Debug.Log("s");
        FindNextCard("j", x, y + 1);
        cross = 0;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yees great it works! Like it can easily find the road is closed! Thats great, thanks. But the function is now calling only once. For further actions i need to call it always twice from the sides where the string road is asigned.

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow what you want your code to do. Maybe rather than explaining how many times a method need to be called you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Okay, sorry been on a vacation. So i have the base card that has just been layed and i need it to find another card with the variable "R", every road card has two variables with "R" and when i find the right side (FindScoringRoad()) the second function has to find another card in that direction. When the card is found it goes back to the first function and so on until the card is not found. This is where the whole proces ends.  But if the card found is the card that started the function, it should say that the road is closed. Imagine it like electric.

Comment: I hope it easier to understand now, my codw is a mess :D. The problem is that it doesnt work because something is setting the function once more for the third time.